# get image contain the attribute onclick then hide the img

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

selector can get image contain the attribute onclick

within the onclick there is a JS code ( windows.open ....href start with (/dailyTickets/front/requesttype.form.php)  )

i want some thing like this :

```
 var attr = $('img').attr('onclick');
    if(typeof attr !== 'undefined' && attr !== false)
    {
$ImgIndex = $('img').attr('onclick').value().indexOf("var w = window.open('/dailyTickets/front/requesttype.form.php").index();

       if ($('img').attr('onclick').value().indexOf("var w = window.open('/dailyTickets/front/requesttype.form.php") == 0)
    {
       $('img:eq('"+$ImgIndex +"').hide();
    }
    }
```

you can test it here : http://jsfiddle.net/zu44E/3/

here is the image :

```
<img 
    alt="" 
    title="Ajouter" 
    src="/dailyTickets/pics/add_dropdown.png" 
    style="cursor:pointer; margin-left:2px;" 
    onclick="var w = window.open('/dailyTickets/front/requesttype.form.php?popup=1&amp;rand=1489777051', 'glpipopup', 'height=400, width=1000, top=100, left=100, scrollbars=yes' );w.focus();"
></img>
```

Comment: You already asked this exact question an hour ago. Please do not repost a question if you don't like the provided answers.

Comment: i have tried to delete the other one , but i can't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your method is slightly off.  First of all.  Here's my update:

http://jsfiddle.net/zu44E/7/

Here are the major changes I made:

1. After selecting an `attr` you don't get the value of that attr by calling `value()`
2. If you assign a variable to a series of chained function calls, what you end up with is the *last* value in the chain not the *first* so the value of your `$ImgContains` variable, had your method worked, would have been a true/false because you equate the `indexOf` to 0 (thus boolean, true or false)
3. Take advantage of jquery.  Jquery can do bulk operations on records.  You don't need to go element-by-element looking for things.  In the case you need to do a test that's more in depth and it is more or less element by element, use iterative jquery methods such as `filter`

Comment: this is it , tnks dudde ^_^

Comment: please @Eli Gassert , when i tried to use under the 'Echo ' php , it doesn't work 
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\"> $(function()
  {
            $ImgContains = $('img').filter(function() 
                                           {
                                               return $(this).attr('onclick').indexOf(\"var w = window.open('/dailyTickets/front/requesttype.form.php\") == 0; 
                                           });
            alert($ImgContains.length);
           $ImgContains.hide();
  });  </script>" ;

Comment: don't echo it.  PHP can mix HTML and server-side PHP code.  So just output it as straight up HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want this?  this gets all the images with the attribute onclick

```
$('img[onclick]')
```

To hide all images with that attribute

```
$('img[onclick]').hide()
```